# Grothendieck group of representations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

For a linearly reductive group $G$ over $k$ we consider the bounded derived category of finite dimensional representations $D^b(\mathrm{Repr}(G))$. Is the Grothendick group $K_0(D^b(\mathrm{Repr}(G))$ finitely generated?

Comment: In addition to abx's answer: have a look at Serre's 'Groupe de Grothendieck des schémas en groupes réductifs déployés' (Pub. IHES).

Answer (score 6):

Only if the semi-simple part of $G$ is trivial. The category $\mathrm{Repr}(G)$ is semi-simple, so $K_0(D^b(\mathrm{Repr}(G))$ is simply the  representation ring $R(G)$. If $G$ is semi-simple this is a free abelian group with basis the set of dominant weights, which is infinite. In general, as soon as you have a nontrivial semi-simple part you'll get this infinite rank factor.

Comment: Since the category of representations is semi-simple this is a completely trivial situation. I am sure you can do the exercise.